# Como mudar o ponto de corte (cut-off) na função glm?

Tags: r

Tenho o segiunte banco de dados, onde pretendo fazer uma regressão logística:

```
set.seed(1)

dataset <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(6, runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  y = as.factor(sample(0:1, 30, replace = TRUE))
)
```

Considere a função:

```
my <- glm(y ~ x.1, family = binomial, data = dataset)
summary(my)
```

- É possível modificar o ponto de corte da análise? Por padrão, a mesma vem com `.5`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Após ajustar o modelo, crie um vetor com as probabilidades previstas. Por exemplo,

```
predict(my, newdata = dataset, type = "response")
##         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
## 0.5939177 0.5464655 0.6365774 0.6446637 0.6239940 0.5303579 0.5328488 0.5466660 
##         9        10        11        12        13        14        15        16 
## 0.5503314 0.5417098 0.6458154 0.6415483 0.5260277 0.6029462 0.5471655 0.5380448 
##        17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24 
## 0.5302498 0.5838713 0.6385566 0.5903019 0.5627473 0.5493866 0.4831309 0.5645080 
##        25        26        27        28        29        30 
## 0.6018940 0.5328032 0.4676268 0.4963086 0.5694663 0.5800685
```

Com este vetor de probabilidades criado, é possível estabelecer qualquer critério desejado para que a variável resposta seja classificada como resultado positivo. Abaixo estabeleço pontos de corte em 0.1, 0.5 e 0.8:

```
ifelse(predict(my, newdata = dataset, type = "response") > 0.1, 1, 0)
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
##  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 
## 28 29 30 
##  1  1  1 
ifelse(predict(my, newdata = dataset, type = "response") > 0.5, 1, 0)
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
##  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  0 
## 28 29 30 
##  0  1  1 
ifelse(predict(my, newdata = dataset, type = "response") > 0.8, 1, 0)
##  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
##  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
## 28 29 30 
##  0  0  0
```